# Issue with apex:map

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, map

I have a map, `Map<Id, Contact> contactsMap` in my apex class where key is the contact id and value is the contact itself. I am iterating over this map in visualforce page to get the contact's Location and mark it in the map(I have other functionality in the page with individual contact. Hence used a map. Using a list of contacts don't suffice my requirement). Below is the snippet of vf code:

```
    <apex:repeat value="{!contactsMap}" var="con">  
         <apex:map width="100%" height="320px" mapType="roadmap" zoomLevel="17" center="{!con.Address__c}" >        
              <apex:mapMarker id="mymap" position="{!con.Address__c}" rendered="true"/>     
         </apex:map> 
    </apex:repeat>
```

The above piece of code isn't saving and the page throws the compile error as below:

> Invalid type for attribute `<apex:map id="mymap" center>:` must be
>   either String or Map.

Can someone let me know where I have went wrong and how this can be solved.

Comment: What is the type of Address__c field?

Comment: It is textarea field. @LanceShi

Answer (score 2):

An `apex:repeat` of a map iterates over the map keys so this is the required syntax:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!contactsMap}" var="key">  
    <apex:map width="100%" height="320px" mapType="roadmap" zoomLevel="17" center="{!contactsMap[key].Address__c}">        
        <apex:mapMarker id="mymap" position="{!contactsMap[key].Address__c}" rendered="true"/>     
    </apex:map> 
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Sorry thats my mistake. I have copied the question wrong but I have actually written it the way you mentioned. The error is coming with above code only. @keithc

Comment: @lalithar OK then make sure the Address__c field is a string field of some type (e.g. text or picklist).

Comment: I made the field type to be text from textarea. I still have the issue. I don't think the issue is with field type, because if I query only one record and remove using apex:repeat, that is working fine and map is shown on the page.

Comment: @lalithar If you do need to have the `center` attribute working, all I can suggest is for you to check that your data matches one of the [documented formats](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_map.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Sahil Ravi:
@Lalitha: try this it worked

```
<apex:page Controller="ContactMap">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:repeat value="{!mapCont}" var="con">
            <apex:map width="100%" height="320px" mapType="roadmap" zoomLevel="17" center="{!mapCont[con].MailingCountry},{!mapCont[con].MailingStreet},{!mapCont[con].MailingCity},{!mapCont[con].MailingState}">        
               <apex:mapMarker id="mymap" position="{!mapCont[con].MailingCountry},{!mapCont[con].MailingStreet},{!mapCont[con].MailingCity},{!mapCont[con].MailingState}" rendered="true"/>
            </apex:map>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<apex:repeat value="{!contactsMap.values()}" var="con">`

Comment: Does map.values() work in page?

Answer (score 0):

Sahil @Lalitha: A string that represents an address. For example, "1 Market Street, San Francisco, CA". The address is geocoded to determine its latitude and longitude.